# How do i use Phonegap's WaitingDialog Plugin in my project

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

https://github.com/guidosabatini/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WaitingDialog

I found this Waitling Dialogue Plugin for Phonegap. But i don't know how to use this, i mean where to put the files?

So please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and put the **WaitingDialog.java** inside main package in src.

Then download and include the **WaitingDialog.js** file in your in the html file. Something like the following:

Then call necessary functions:

// To SHOW a modal waiting dialog

```
window.plugins.waitingDialog.show("Your dialog text");
```

// To HIDE the dialog

```
window.plugins.waitingDialog.hide();
```

[I haven't tested, but hopefully it will work.]

**Alternative Solution:**

If you are using jQuery Mobile then another solution can be to use [jquery.mobile.utils](https://github.com/scottwb/jquery.mobile.utils) to show the loader.

Download and include the **jquery.mobile.utils.js** file in your html file. Then call necessary functions like below:

// Params: jqm theme swatch, and message text

```
$.mobile.utils.showWaitBox("a", "Hang on while I do work...");
```

// ... some time later...

```
$.mobile.utils.hideWaitBox();
```

[This one is tested and works fine.]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

As you told i put the WaitingDialog.java inside the src folder, now when i open the project in eclipe its saying following error on line 1 package org.apache.cordova;

The declared package "org.apache.cordova" does not match the expected package ""

What can i do now?

Comment: And is mobile.utils would similar to Android Phone Loading window?

Comment: In https://github.com/scottwb/jquery.mobile.utils it has two files 1. jquery.mobile.utils.js 2. jquery.mobile.utils.js.coffee. Am i need to include both files in my html?

Comment: @rkaartikeyan: The first one.

Comment: As you told i put the WaitingDialog.java inside the src folder, now when i open the project in eclipe its saying following error on line 1 package org.apache.cordova; The declared package "org.apache.cordova" does not match the expected package "" What can i do now?

Comment: @rkaartikeyan: The loader will be like this: [http://imgur.com/tlLZpq0](http://imgur.com/tlLZpq0)

Comment: Which one bro? that WaitingDialog.js Loader? or the Mobile.Utils?

Comment: Anyway thanks for you help, my loading problem solved with your jquery.mobile.utility... But i am expecting to show alerts like Android...

Comment: Its not working for me even after adding the plugins...someone help me.Iam using coredova latest version in android..